# Let $a,b\ge 0$ be integers such that $2^na+b$ is a perfect square $\forall n>0$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, contest-math, arithmetic

> Let $a,b\ge 0$ be integers such that $2^na+b$ is a perfect square $\forall n>0$. Show that $a=0$.

I have no idea how to start this problem since I don't see any arithmetic proprety that I can use in such a problem.

Thanks !

Comment: Find such $a$ or show $a=0$?

Comment: I'd start by considering it valid first for $n$ and $n+1$ and see if any sort of induction argument work.

Comment: I do not understand what this dot after $2^n$ means?

Comment: A note: This is from Polish olympiad, 2001 or 2000.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let $2^n a+ b =a_n^2$ for some sequence $(a_n)_{n=1}^\infty$. We shall prove that the sequence $(a_n)$ is constant, which will establish that $a=0$.

Suppose that $a\neq 0$. Then, $a_n$ is a strictly increasing sequence. Observe that,
$$
a_n^2 = 2^n a+b\Rightarrow (2a_n)^2 = 2^{n+2}a+4b=a_{n+2}^2 +3b \Rightarrow 3 b=(2a_n-a_{n+2})(2a_n+a_{n+2}).
$$
Now, this immediately implies, for all $n$, $2a_n +a_{n+2}$ divides $3b$, which in turn yields $2a_n+a_{n+2}\leqslant 3b$ for all $n$. However, $b$ is fixed; and thus, if $a\neq 0$, the sequence $(a_n)$ is unbounded, yielding a contradiction.

**Edit** To address John's comment  below: This all hold of course provided $2a_n-a_{n+2}\neq 0$ for all $n$. Say, there is an $n$ making this object $0$, which would yield $b=0$. Now, we have $2^n a$ is a perfect square for all $n$, which is a contradiction: If $2^n a =x^2$ then $2^{n+1}a =2x^2$, which cannot be a perfect square (easy to see, let  $y^2=2x^2$, then $2\mid y$, letting $y=2y_1$, we get $x^2=2y_1^2$, yielding $2\mid x$, which, in turn yielding $y_1^2=2x_1^2$, an infinite descent is occurring).

Comment: From $3b=(2a_n-a_{n+2})(2a_n+a_{n+2})$, you haven't accounted for the possibility of $2a_n - a_{n+2} = 0$ since, if true, then $2a_n + a_{n+2}$ can be anything. For this case, $4a_n^2 = a_{n+2}^2$ but since $4a_n^2 = a_{n+2}^2 + 3b$, then $b = 0$. However, if $b = 0$, $a$ would need to have an odd # of factors of $2$ when $n$ is odd & an even # of factors of $2$ when $n$ is even, which can't happen if $a \neq 0$. With these extra checks, as far as I can tell, your solution will then be complete.

Comment: John, thanks for the notice. Indeed, I fixed that part of the argument. If $b=0$, then $2^n a=x^2$ implies $2^{n+1}a=2x^2 = y^2$, which is impossible unless $a =0$ (easy to see, I outlined how to handle this above).

Comment: You're welcome for the help. I realized later that if $2a_n - a_{n+2} = 0$, then $b = 0$ directly from $3b=(2a_n-a_{n+2})(2a_n+a_{n+2})$. I made an unnecessarily complicated argument to show this in my comment above. Regarding the case where $b = 0$, infinite descent is an interesting way to handle it.